# SolrCloud throw error while creating second collection "Underlying core creation failed while creating collection"

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I was run 2 node in solr with single zookeeper to configure. I'll try to create a collection like location Its create successfully and then try to create second collection like contact. Its throw error.

**Make API Call for create collection**

`curl -sS 'http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=CREATE&name=contact&numShards=2&replicationFactor=2&maxShardsPerNode=2&collection.configName=conf_contact'`

**Response for create collection**

````
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":400,
    "QTime":1154},
  "failure":{
    "192.168.1.121:8983_solr":"org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException:Error from server at http://192.168.1.121:8983/solr: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'contact_shard2_replica_n6': Unable to create core [contact_shard2_replica_n6] Caused by: org.opensextant.solrtexttagger.TaggerRequestHandler",
    "192.168.1.121:8983_solr":"org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException:Error from server at http://192.168.1.121:8983/solr: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'contact_shard1_replica_n3': Unable to create core [contact_shard1_replica_n3] Caused by: org.opensextant.solrtexttagger.TaggerRequestHandler",
    "192.168.1.157:8983_solr":"org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException:Error from server at http://192.168.1.157:8983/solr: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'contact_shard2_replica_n5': Unable to create core [contact_shard2_replica_n5] Caused by: org.opensextant.solrtexttagger.TaggerRequestHandler",
    "192.168.1.157:8983_solr":"org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException:Error from server at http://192.168.1.157:8983/solr: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'contact_shard1_replica_n1': Unable to create core [contact_shard1_replica_n1] Caused by: org.opensextant.solrtexttagger.TaggerRequestHandler"},
  "Operation create caused exception:":"org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Underlying core creation failed while creating collection: contact",
  "exception":{
    "msg":"Underlying core creation failed while creating collection: contact",
    "rspCode":400},
  "error":{
    "metadata":[
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
      "root-error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"],
    "msg":"Underlying core creation failed while creating collection: contact",
    "code":400}}```

**Note:** 1 GB for each node solr mem size
````

Comment: check if there are any issues with the configset used for the collection....may be in the schema.xml oe solrconfig.xml

Comment: Also please check for the detailed log...This much of information wont be enough to resolve the issue...check on the logs of other server